# I want to access dynamic generated HTML id using jquery selector in same function

Tags: jquery

```
function render(index){
  var cancel="cancel" + index;
  result = "<a id="' + cancel + '">;
  $('#' + cancel).hide();
  return result;
}
```

I want to access dynamic generated html id using jquery selector in same function. But here I am not able to show border for the `<a>` tag.

If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Show how you use this function, where are you `returning` to?

Comment: There is an obvious syntax error in line 3... Plus that line does _not_ create a DOM element. It defines a string, not more, since you forgot to use jQuery in there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this, as a first step:

```
function render(index) {
  var cancel="cancel"+index;
  result = $('<a id="'+cancel+'">');
  $('#'+cancel).hide();
  return result;
}
```

Note: *this won't work yet*, it is not final. Before you can select such an element you have to add it to the DOM. You probably want to do that by returning the value, but that won't work, except you have a very special situation. Instead you have to add it in an explicit manner. Where should the link go?

If the intention is to add it in an invisible manner, then you should style it by means of styling rules instead of scripting. So hide it by a css rule for example or by simply adding an inline styling rule:

```
$('<a id="'+cancel+'" style="display: none">');
```

Comment: function render(index) {
  var cancel="cancel"+index;                                                                     var result = some + _some code+ '</fieldset></form></td></tr></table>' +
$('<a class="cancelOutClass" id="' + cancelOut + '" >Cancel </a>') + '</div>');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 I am try your code ,html display as OBject Object,on sme cond i have to hide <a>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. It is impossible to read it. There is an `edit` button below your question. That is how you should add details.

Comment: link generated for the dynamic row, and on row click the this result will append to row . depending on flag i have to show or hode <a> but in same function beacuse i am not able to get index value in other function so thats why i am generating dynamic id here and try to hide cancel for some rows for which flag is 0.

Comment: What "flag" are you talking about? Where is it? How can we help if your question is incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....I am accessing dynamic generated html id using Jquery selector in same function

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test1"> Testing 1 </div>   
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createAndGetIdInSameFunction() {
            var id = "test2";
            $("body").append("<div id="+id+">Testing 2 </div>");
            $("#"+id).hide();
        }
        createAndGetIdInSameFunction();
    </script>
</html>
```